# Headings extraction in JS - "If" works but "Else" doesn't

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, extract

I'm trying to run this code and extract all headings with the option to show "doesn't exist" when certain headings well... doesn't exist, but it's not reading the else statement somehow and would be great if you could point me to the right direction.

```
function headingsEx() {
    let h = ["h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6"];
    for (let i of h) {
        if (document.getElementsByTagName(i)) {
            let foundHs = document.querySelectorAll(i)
            for (let c of foundHs) {
                console.log({ [i]: c.textContent })
            };
        } else {
            console.log([i] + " doesn't exist");
        }
    }
}

headingsEx();
```

Comment: It does not return `null` if not found. Try `document.getElementsByTagName(i).length` instead.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp

I tried what you say and it works, but I want to understand it better.

If I try "Try & Catch" should it work? Are there other options?

Comment: Try/catch will only catch if there's an error. Checking for length with let you know if any items were found. Otherwise you'll simply have an empty (length=0) HTML Collection, but the collection will still exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you asked about alternative approaches:

This example grabs all the heading elements using [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), and then uses [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a new array of node names. You can then iterate over the headings array and check to see if each element is included in the `nodeNames` array, and then log the result accordingly.

```js
const arr = ['h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6'];
const headings = document.querySelectorAll(arr.join(','));

const nodeNames = [...headings].map(heading => {
  return heading.nodeName.toLowerCase();
});

arr.forEach(el => {
  if (nodeNames.includes(el)) {
    console.log(`${el}: exists.`)
  } else {
    console.log(`${el}: does not exist.`)
  }
});
```

```html
<h1>Hi</h1>
<h3>Hi</h3>
<h4>Hi</h4>
<h6>Hi</h6>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName), `document.getElementsByTagName(i)` returns a live HTMLCollection. No where in the docs does it say it returns anything other than that. So it is safe to say that `document.getElementsByTagName(i)` will always be truthy (i.e. not `null` or `false`). You can instead check the `length` member. It will be greater than `0` if at least one of the element exists.

```
function headingsEx() {
    let h = ["h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6"];
    for (let i of h) {
        if (document.getElementsByTagName(i).length) {
            let foundHs = document.querySelectorAll(i)
            for (let c of foundHs) {
                console.log({ [i]: c.textContent })
            };
        } else {
            console.log([i] + " doesn't exist");
        }
    }
}

headingsEx();
```

Answer (score 1):

An empty array is truthy (usually anyway) so even when `getElementsByTagName(i)` finds nothing and returns an empty array, the "then" block is still the one that gets executed.

```js
console.log('is [] true?');
if ([]) {
  console.log('yes');
} else {
  console.log('no');
}

console.log('---');

console.log('is [99] true?');
if ([99]) {
  console.log('yes');
} else {
  console.log('no');
}
```

If you're wondering why I said "usually", see https://xavierchow.github.io/2015/12/15/js-coercion/ but don't worry if you can't follow it. It was news to me as well.